# implementation body syntax and source

Tags: methods, syntax, implementation

Hi can someone explain the source of the commands/terms and the syntax of the below method implementation code?

```
- (IBAction)changeLabel:(id)sender {
 NSString *contents = [ [self simpleTextField] text];

 NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello, %@",       contents];
 [self.simpleLabel setText:message];
 }
```

Perhaps easier if you answer the below questions:

1. where did the programmer get/learn the term/command "simpleTextField". from? Is this a command particular to NSString? Whatever it is, can you provide me a website which lists all these commands, so that I can learn the vocabulary needed to fill in my codes?
2. For the part after the = sign in the [] brackets, is there a particular syntax that programmers can follow? Does

[[self simpleTextField]text] follow the syntax

[[which-object in-where]do-what]?

Otherwise what is the syntax its actually following? I can't really figure because the subsequent line [NSString stringWithFormat......] seems to not follow a same syntax. Is there a particular syntax you have to follow? Otherwise is there any other guideline to how to type in the code or code to type in?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit oversimplified, but...

The syntax for Objective-C is [object function:parameters].

So [self simpleTextField] corrosponds to what other languages would write as self.simpleTextField. ( or this.getSimpleTextField() in case of java)

So simpleTextField is a property of the object designated by self (this).

Depending on what kind of project it is, it is probably defined in the header file (.h).

It is probably bound to a UI element from the Storyboard.

Objective C is just different enough, that you are not going to just glean how it works, by reading someone elses code.

I would suggest going through some tutorials.
http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/